# How to set Everything search to ignore punctuation in filenames?

Tags: windows, filenames, everything

In the past [Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/) ignored punctuation in filenames and I always admired the program for that — a search `king kong` would also display folders or files `king.kong.1933`, `king-kong-1976` and `Peter_Jackson's_King_Kong_Gamers_Edition`. After apparently changing some setting I now must type the filenames exactly as they are saved on disk.

How can I set a "selective" search as requested?

Comment: For comparison, here are screenshots of my settings : [menu *Search*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9Llj.jpg) and [*Options > Search*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qF9hO.jpg).

Comment: @harrymc: Thank you. Disabling "enable regex" resolved the issue, I've accidentally hit the `Ctrl` + `R` hotkey at some point. You can post an answer.

Comment: Done as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After comparison with my settings for voidtools Everything,
the poster has found that the problematic setting was "Enable Regex"
from the *Search* menu.

I include my settings below for future reference :

---

[image]

---

[image]